# SQLCMD.exe window is not opening

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sqlcmd

On `Windows Server 2012` we have `SQL Server 2008-R2 Enterprise` installed that does have [SQLCMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2014) but when I try to open the utility its black console window opens for a fraction of a second and then disappears. What may be the cause and how can we open the window and/or resolve the issue?

Comment: I have the same issue with SSMS v18 on top of SQL 2017 Express. After I installed a Kofax Product which works good in my instance of SQL Express, the SSMS just opens for a second and then dissapears not giving me a chance to log to the instance of SQL I could before the instalation to connect. SQL itself is running well, the DBs are good - through the other programs which connect to it, but SSMS fails to work and to offer me the login screen. (It's on a VM - MS 2016 Standard on Virtual Box - all new installed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlcmd is really intended to be run like a terminal program from a shell such as command prompt (cmd.exe) or PowerShell. If you're just running `sqlcmd.exe` from the Run window or the start menu, the default behavior is to open a trusted connection to the local system. It's equivalent to running:

```
sqlcmd.exe -S 127.0.0.1 -E
```

If the window just displays a black screen, it's because it's trying to connect and isn't succeeding. If you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, you should get the message "Canceling connection. Please wait...Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Operation was canceled.." or similar.

If you're unable to connect, perhaps you're not specifying the correct parameters to connect to the instance, or the instance is stopped, or the instance isn't configured correctly.

Try connecting with SQL Server Management Studio or another SQL client. Check SQL Server Configuration Manager to be sure that your instance is started and that it's listening appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my confusion. I used the `cmd` and typed `sqlcmd` and got the error: Login failed for user `myLoginName`. This seems to indicates that I don't have any access to the SQL server. But I can connect to the server (and my db) using `SSMS`. What I may be missing here?